# Where can I find low level Sound Programming Theory Tutorials

Tags: audio, low-level-code

I am an intermediate graphics programmer. I want to learn audio/sound processing theory from the ground up.

Just like how "A pixel" and its components R,G,B,A is the fundamental part of Graphics programming. I want to know about sound programming in similar lines.

Can anyone point me to good links? Also I would like to know some libraries (preferably portable) which allow me to manipulate sound. Something which can directly work on mp3, amr files.

I don't mind book recommendations too :)

Comment: Read the book http://www.amazon.com/Audio-Programming-Book-Richard-Boulanger/dp/0262014467

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before getting your hands dirty with the very low levels (C/C++) I'd suggest playing around with higher level tools such as [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) (a free Matlab clone). You might need to install the [Signal Processing toolkit](http://www.tty1.net/blog/2009-09-12-filters-with-gnu-octave_en.html) too.  This should give you a good testbed for playing around with FFTs, convolution, filtering and the like, and also lets you graph the results.  I'd suggest finding a good book on signal processing to get familiar with the concepts, then if you want to get into DSP algorithms, [MusicDSP.org](http://musicdsp.org/) is worth a look.

If you want an existing framework to work with then look at [CLAM](http://clam-project.org/).

A pixel in graphics programming is analogous to a single sampled point in audio.  A digitised image is comprised of a 2d array of pixels; a digitised audio signal is comprised of a sequence of sample points, each point correponding to an amplitude.  The rest you'll find in the books...

Answer (score 5):

Some old but good practical texts which might be able to pick up cheaply on Amazon:

- [*Musical Applications of Microprocessors* -- Hal Chamberlin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0810457687)
- [*Elements of Computer Music* -- F. Richard Moore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132525526)
- [*C Language Algorithms for Digital Signal Processing* -- Paul M Embree & Bruce Kimble](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131334069)

Answer (score 0):

Sound On Sound's [Synth Secrets](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/allsynthsecrets.htm) series provides a fairly good basic introduction to the concepts of sound synthesis.