# What's a good resource for learning about creating software for signal processing

Tags: signal-processing

I'd like to programatically do some signal processing on a live sound feed.

Specifically I'd like to be able to isolate certain bands of frequencies and play around with phase shifting.

I've not worked in this area before from a purely software perspective and a quick google search turned up very little useful information.

Does anyone know of any good information resources for this topic area?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854173/where-can-i-find-low-level-sound-programming-theory-tutorials and numerous other SO questions and answers tagged [signal-processing], [FFT], [spectrum], etc.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is a good starting point. It has the necessary toolboxes and functions that will allow you to capture audio signals, run different kind of filters over them and write them to wav files. The UI is easy to navigate through and it's simple enough to generate plots and visualize results.

http://www.mathworks.com/products/signal/

If, however, you're looking to develop real-world applications, then Python can come in handy. They have toolkits like SciPy, Numpy, Audiolab that offer the same functions as Matlab does.

http://www.scipy.org

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20121108212849/http://numpy.scipy.org:80/)

http://scikits.appspot.com/audiolab

In a nutshell, Matlab is good for testing ideas and prototyping, Python is good for testing as well as real-world application development. And Python is free. Matlab might cost you if you're not a student anymore.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dspguide.com/

This is a super excellent reference on digital signal processing techniques in general.  It's not a programming guide, per se, but covers the techniques and the theory clearly and simply, and provides pseudocode and examples so that you can implement in the language of your choice.  You'll be hard up to find a more complete reference, and you can download it for free online!